# Generic JavaScript collapse function for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to write a generic JavaScript that would rename the collapsible link when clicked from "Expand" to "Hide" and vice versa.

I wrote the below code for that in jQuery:

```
$(".collapse").collapse();

$(".collapse").on('show', function() {
    $("a[data-target='#"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").text($("a[data-target='#"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").attr('data-on-hidden'))
});
$(".collapse").on('hidden', function() {
    $("a[data-target='#"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").text($("a[data-target='#"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").attr('data-on-active'))
});
```

which interacts with the following HTML:

```
<div class="collapse in" id="collapse-fields">
Expandable content
 </div>
 <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-fields" 
      data-on-hidden="Hide" data-on-active="Expand">Expand</a>
```

I am new to jQuery and I was wondering if my code is written in a right way or if there is a better approach to write such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for a generic solution, this should work anywhere : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/WN3vV/)

```js
var $togglers = $('[data-toggle="collapse"]');    // Elements that toggle a collapsible
$togglers.each(function() {                       // Do the same thing for all elements
    var $this = $(this);
    var $collapsible = $($this.data('target'));   // Collapsibles of this iteration
    $collapsible.on('hidden', function() {
        var text = $this.data('on-hidden');       // Get the data-on-hidden attribute value
        text && $this.text(text);                 // If it has text to replace, change it
    }).on('shown', function() {
        var text = $this.data('on-active');       // Get the data-on-active attribute value
        text && $this.text(text);                 // If it has text to replace, change it
    });
});
```

You just need to add the `data-on-hidden` and `data-on-active` attributes to **any element** that toggles a collapsible.

**Note :** I took the liberty of switching the values of the attributes so that *on-hidden* correspond to when it's hidden and *on-active* when it's visible.